# Does a NYY or NYM cable affects a CAT6 cables transmission if they are crossed?

Tags: current, cables

I get an unfinished job and really hard trying to complete it. Ex-engineer of my company had designed the cable tray system as a cable tray should used for both light current cables and heavy current cables.

I am in doubt about using light and heavy current cables in a tray. I will use a separator to keep them separate but somehow they have to **pass over eachother in some points.**

I am transmissing voice and image with **CAT6** cables (entryphone system) and heavy current will be in **5x6 NYY** cables.

Is the NYY cable affect the CAT6 cables image and voice when they are crossed?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the quality of the CAT6 cable. Industrial cables have larger cross section and very thick shield, also two layer shield. It is a common practice to place the signal cables on one side and power cables to the other side of the tray. If you put a separator is yet better, the best would be separate trays.
If the cables go underground, you should have also two separate hoses.

It is almost inevitable to cross the power cables at certain section. Try to lay 
the CAT6 as distant as possible from power, even when you cross it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the NYY cable affect the CAT6 cables image and voice when they are
>   crossed?

Crossing cables can affect each other but the general practice is to use balanced drivers and balanced differential receivers on the circuits that might be susceptible to noise. It's still important to use the "right" cable of course but, just using the "right" cable and not paying attention to drivers and receivers is asking for trouble: -

[image]

The top picture shows an unbalanced driver - noise can more easily get onto one wire than the other and, as a result the receiver output is affected by that noise. The bottom picture shows a balanced driver and, as expected, noise will affect both signals about the same but, because signals are inverted, the effect of the noise is cancelled at the receiver.

Balancing not only means making sure impedances are balanced (thus noise affects both lines the same) but can also mean (and be enhanced by) using differential drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the maximum coupling occurs when wires are in parallel, and minimum if they cross at right angles.